# Pointer to An Array of Type Struct Segmentation Error

Tags: c

So in main I pass the address of menu_items array to function initialize

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    struct vm vm;
    struct menu_item menu_items[NUM_MENU_ITEMS];

    initialize(&vm, argc, argv, &menu_items);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

In function initialize I call menu_init (I've removed unnecessary lines)

```
BOOLEAN initialize(struct vm * vm, int argc, char * argv[], struct menu_item (* menu_items)[])
{
    menu_init(menu_items);
}
```

And here's menu_init

```
void menu_init(struct menu_item (* menu_items)[NUM_MENU_ITEMS])
{
    int i;

    static struct menu_item menuTable[] = {
        { "Display Items", &displayItems },
        { "Purchase Items", &purchaseItems },
        { "Save and Exit", &saveExit },
        { "Add Item", &addItem },
        { "Remove Item", &removeItem },
        { "Display Coins", &displayCoins },
        { "Reset Stock", &resetStock },
        { "Reset Coins", &resetCoins },
        { "Abort Program", &abortProgram }
    };

    for (i = 0; i < NUM_MENU_ITEMS; i++) {
        strcpy((*menu_items[i]).name, menuTable[i].name);
        (*menu_items[i]).func = menuTable[i].func;
    }
}
```

Struct menu_item looks like this

```
struct menu_item
{
    char name[ITEM_NAME_LEN+1];
    menu_ptr func;
};
```

Strangely this works on my home pc but gets a segmentation fault on my uni's server. Any ideas?

Comment: `(*menu_items[i])` ===> `(*menu_items)[i]`. And unless `menuTable` happens to be  the same size *or* larger than `NUM_MENU_ITEMS`, you'll be reading from undefined memory space, and invoking undefined behavior with that loop.

Comment: can you please paste whole program as it is. It isHelpful in analysing the program.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that "declaration mimicks use", so in your initialisation function, where you pass a pointer to an array of menu item structs:

```
struct menu_item (*menu_items)[]
```

you should access them in the same fashion:

```
(*menu_items)[i].func = menuTable[i].func;
```

as WhozCraig has pointed out. (Declaring the dimension in the argument actually hides a useful warning here: `(*menu_items[1])` points after the whole chunk of items, which is into undefined territory.)

But I think your approach to the problem is too complicated in the first place. You don't need to pass a pointer to the array; it is sufficient to pass the array:

```
void menu_init(struct menu_item menu_items[])
{
    int i;

    static struct menu_item menuTable[] = {
        // ... snip ...
    };

    for (i = 0; i < NUM_MENU_ITEMS; i++) {
        strcpy(menu_items[i].name, menuTable[i].name);
        menu_items[i].func = menuTable[i].func;
    }
}

void initialize(struct menu_item menu_items[])
{
    menu_init(menu_items);
}

int main()
{
    struct menu_item menu_items[NUM_MENU_ITEMS];

    initialize(menu_items);

    // .. snip ...
}
```

You'd only need to pass the pointer, if the array base itself could change, but you don't want that.

(And maybe even that is too complicated. Why not just declare the menu items in file scope and work on them directly?)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to show how the structure look like.
In the first look I could see that `strcpy` is the one which is causing the segmentation fault. I see you are not allocating any memory using new/malloc to the pointer inside the strcuture for each menu item.